# Can´t make jupyter notebook work in Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

On my windows PC, i have Anaconda installed, but today i could not open Jupyter Notebook correctly. When i use these commands to set up an enviornment, i can open the Jupyter notebook.

`conda activate [name_of_the_environment]`

`jupyter notebook`

The error occurs when internet explorer opens the Jupyter notebook, because i can't access to my ipynb files or any other. The page just stays like this (in blanc, like it does not end loading):

[Internet explorer general site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70I48.png)

[Trying to open a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clk7Y.png)

I am not having any connection problems and this happens regardless of the file size.
I also tried updating Anaconda, but it didn´t work.

Code written in the terminal:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyCaH.png)

Comment: Can you show what is written in the terminal where you ran `jupyter notebook`

Comment: Do other browsers work?

Comment: Yes, i just put the code in the question (final part)

Comment: I can't use other browsers either